# Visible code on my website from my Google Analytics tag

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, facebook-pixel

I have a website in which I installed Google tag manager, and been using it for more than a year without any issue. Recently some of the code of the Google Analytics Tag has been showing in the page. It's visible and displayed at the bottom of all the pages, which caused my website to be flagged as spam and blocked by the provider. I've managed to recover my account and I'm trying to get rid of that issue so I don't end up losing it again. I tried reinstalling the Fb pixel, the Google Tag manager code, Fixing the GA4 tag... but nothing seems to work.

This is what it looks like:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', { 'transaction_id': 't_12345', 'currency': 'USD', 'value': 1.23, user_data: { email_address: 'johnsmith@email.com', phone_number: '1234567890', address: { first_name: 'john', last_name: 'smith', city: 'menlopark', region: 'ca', postal_code: '94025', country: 'usa', }, }, items: [{ item_name: 'foo', quantity: 5, price: 123.45, item_category: 'bar', item_brand : 'baz', }], });
```

And it keeps repeating itself.

Has anyone seen this before? Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Thank you so much!

I tried Fixing the GA4 tag... from the start but as soon as I install the Google tag manager code it shows up again.

Comment: You might need to find the tag in your GTM one by one to check which tag has this code. The tag type should be `custom html`

Comment: Hi @darrelltw thank you so much!! I just tried and found that piece of code in a few different tags, I have no idea on how in got there but I jus deleted it and everything went back to normal!! Thanks again!!